# Error: Leading too small: minimum 12pt, saw values as small as 11.9pt

Tags: errors, fontsize, paper-size

I'm submitting my assignment and get error from the automated format checker.

First of all, I use:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,twocolumn,10pt]{article}

Error: Leading too small: minimum 12pt, saw values as small as 11.9pt
```

Why do you think this problems occur? Can I force if it happens for some reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless there is something strange going on in the remainder of your preamble, the automated format checker is just wrong: With those options, latex will set `\baselineskip=12pt` so either some latex package is later overriding this, or the format checker has a bug.

Comment: You can try adding `\showthe\baselineskip` somewhere in your document to check whether that length is indeed `12pt`. If it is, you may want to increase it slightly to make the format checker happy.

Comment: I guess perhaps the checker might be using "postscript points" (1/72 in) instead of traditional points (1/72.27 in). Although 12pt == 11.96bp, so still not as small as 11.9 after rounding. Maybe setting `\baselineskip=12bp` will satisfy the checker.

Comment: @Bruno Le Floch, @Lev Bishop, after compiling couple of times, the checker stop warning me. Thanks for your answers.